# Regex - replace start and end character sequences

Tags: java, regex

hope this is a reasonable way to try explain my goal.

My goal is to update strings from

```
"unchanged DETECT_OPEN blah DETECT_CLOSE unchanged"
```

to

```
"unchanged UPDATED_OPEN blah UPDATED_CLOSE unchanged"
```

So for

```
DETECT_OPEN = [
DETECT_CLOSE = ]

UPDATED_OPEN = <
UPDATED_CLOSE = >
```

on an input string of

```
"this stays the same [i am wrapped] nothing to do here"
```

after processing it is

```
"this stays the same <i am wrapped> nothing to do here"
```

Is there a good way to tackle this with regex?
I'm in java; so a java specific example would be ideal; but any regex is welcome; I'll be happy to try take it from there.

Not sure if it'll make any difference; but the OPEN and CLOSE markers can be more than 1 character; and not equal in length.

So for example

```
DETECT_OPEN = ||
DETECT_CLOSE = |
```

Simple example:

```
 "this stays the same ||i am wrapped| nothing to do here"
```

And the reason I can't use multiple find replaces - is for scenarios like

```
"this isn't an open || because it doesn't close. This open || is  closed |, this close | was never opened"
```

So after processing it would be

```
"this isn't an open || because it doesn't close. This open < is  closed >, this close | was never opened"
```

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Can you give an example with _more than 1 character_ as marker? Also how to identify the marker's length? Special rule?

Comment: Your example makes a solution more difficult. Because you want the nearest open + close, your program would have to read-ahead past the first open and look for a corresponding close. I'm thinking a valid solution might be nested open + close, as in: "this isn't an open < because it doesn't close. This open < is  closed >, this close > was never opened"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a capture group:

```
String replaced = input.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "<$1>");
```

This creates a new string, with the `[...]` replaced with `<...>`.
The `$1` refers to the expression that was captured within the first matched `(...)` in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to use regex? If not, a simpler solution would be:

```
"this stays the same [i am wrapped] nothing to do here".replace("[","<").replace("]",">");
```

And for a generalized solution:

```
String target = "this stays the same OPEN i am wrapped CLOSE nothing to do here";
String DETECT_OPEN = "OPEN";
String DETECT_CLOSE = "CLOSE";
String UPDATED_OPEN = "REPLACED OPEN";
String UPDATED_CLOSE = "REPLACED CLOSE";

String replaced = target.replace(DETECT_OPEN, UPDATED_OPEN).replace(DETECT_CLOSE, UPDATED_CLOSE);
```

**Edit**:

This is to answer your edited question. Note that this solution will work for delimiters of various lengths as long as the close delimiter is not contained in the open delimiter. However, it will not match opened delimiters with closed delimiters. The balancing parenthesis problem is a much harder problem than replacing strings. Code sample can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/check-for-balanced-parentheses).

Because of the balancing parenthesis problem, I would not recommend a regex.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants a generalized solution. Like, let the end user provide these four strings. That said, you are correct - there isn't a need for regex here, as [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) should do the trick in any case.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion; but I updated the question to provide examples where I don't think separate find and replace calls will work. The update needs to ensure it only replaces OPENs which are matched by some CLOSE

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a small help from Apache commons StringUtils. (If that is unavailable, you could implement the countMatches yourself.)

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Brackets {
    final String DETECT_OPEN = "[";
    final String DETECT_CLOSE = "]";
    final String UPDATED_OPEN = "<";
    final String UPDATED_CLOSE = ">";

    public String matchingBrackets(String replaceMe) {
        int openCount = StringUtils.countMatches(replaceMe, DETECT_OPEN);
        int closeCount = StringUtils.countMatches(replaceMe, DETECT_CLOSE);
        if (openCount != closeCount) {
            // counts unequal, so return unchanged
            return replaceMe;
        }

        String ans = replaceMe;

        for (int i = 0; i < openCount; i++) {
            int nextOpenIndex = StringUtils.indexOf(ans, DETECT_OPEN);
            ans = StringUtils.replace(ans, DETECT_OPEN, UPDATED_OPEN);

            int lastCloseIndex = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(ans, DETECT_CLOSE);
            if (lastCloseIndex < nextOpenIndex) {
                // have reversed open and close, as in  )(
                return replaceMe;
            } else {
                ans = StringUtils.replace(ans, DETECT_CLOSE, UPDATED_CLOSE);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Here is a testNG test.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BracketsTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "BracketsTest")
    public void testMatchingBrackets(String expected, String processMe) throws Exception {
        Brackets brackets = new Brackets();
        assertEquals(expected, brackets.matchingBrackets(processMe));
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] BracketsTest() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"][", "]["},
                {"<>", "[]"},
                {"An unmatched brace [ [] means no change", "An unmatched brace [ [] means no change"},
                {"this stays the same <i am wrapped> nothing to do here", "this stays the same [i am wrapped] nothing to do here"},
                {"this stays the same ]i am wrapped[ nothing to do here", "this stays the same ]i am wrapped[ nothing to do here"},
                {"the outer nested brackets < balance with these < inner >, and here's the outer > .", "the outer nested brackets [ balance with these [ inner ], and here's the outer ] ."},
                {"The left is <balanced> and so is the <right>.", "The left is [balanced] and so is the [right]."}
        };
    }
}
```

Note that the behavior is slightly different for the case:

```
the outer nested brackets [ balance with these [ inner ], and here's the outer ] .
```

I think that these are balanced, while the OP thinks that it is not, possibly because of two open brackets in a row.